# What's the difference between "route" and "track" in OruxMaps?

Tags: terminology, oruxmaps

What's the difference between "route" and "track" in terms of navigation? Is there a conceptual difference or only a technical one?

For example OruxMaps treats the two terms differently:
[image] ([source](http://www.oruxmaps.com/oruxmapsmanual_en.pdf))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waypoints, routes and tracks come from the GPX format specifications. The difference between routes and tracks is as follows:

- Routes are simply a sequence of waypoints for navigation. For example, it can calculate the bearing or the distance to the next point.
- Tracks are the actual recorded path. It is where you've been and when.

Comment: So a "route" is a private case of a "track"?

Comment: Well, kind of, I think. They are both connected points that forms a line. They serves different purposes though.

Comment: A route shows where you plan to go.  A track shows where you actually went.

Answer (score 1):

1
A route shows where you plan to go. A track shows where you actually went. – Peter Bennett Sep 5 '16 at 3:23 This is Correct~!~

Answer (score 0):

On Garmin units (and possibly non Garmin units), the difference is how you get from a Waypoint to the next Waypoint, with a Track the gap between Waypoints is always a straight line, With a Route the gap between Waypoints is 'routed' by following a road, path or other map feature and that map feature must be present, so Routes are map dependant, Tracks are not